# Why I can't put data into the invisible Textbox just like into a string?

Tags: vb6

I tried to use Textbox control just like a string and inserted a sequence of integers into it. But whenever a zero appeared inside of some integer, the reading of the this string was interrupted. Does anybody know why? Thanks in advance.

Complementary information:
The `Text1.Text` property was filled by integers in binary format, that is de facto by couples of ANSI characters (including NULL character).

Comment: There is a reason you need to post code - it helps us understand what the heck you mean and in what context.  if you literally mean integers, then `0` acts as the end of string marker.  Any chars after that will be ignored.  By the way, controls - visible or otherwise - dont make good variables.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

To show a sequence of integers:

```
Dim arr
arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Text1 = Join(arr, ",")
```

The code works just fine on my machine.

Comment: Is it obligatory to store integers only as arabic numbers? (See the discussion above...)